# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager

Tags: java, android, exception, android-viewpager

My application gets all images URL from server and saves that to an `ArrayList` and displays these images in `ViewPager`. But it generates a `IllegalStateException`. Adapter given below:

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Context activity,
                                  ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imgDisplay;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container,
                false);

        imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.cardImage);

            Picasso.with(_activity).load(_imagePaths.get(position)).into(imgDisplay);


        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout, 0);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);

    }
}
```

Adapter created as

```
FullScreenImageAdapter adapter=new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenActivity.this,all_url);


            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the log looks like below:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter
> changed the adapter's contents without calling
> PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1,
> found: 3 Pager id: com.wat.clickzy:id/view_pager Pager class: class
> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class
> com.wat.clickzy.FullScreenImageAdapter
```

Please help me

Comment: Add the code of creating the adapter and assigning.

Comment: For every change that you make in the adapter (this includes inserting, removing...) you need to call notifysetdatachanged on your adapter

Comment: Where i call notifysetdatachanged on adapter?

Comment: Still its no working anyone please help me

Comment: help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `notifysetdatachanged` on the `adapter` that you're using, every time you're adding/removing something to that `adapter`.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) for even more clarity.

Comment: Where i call notifysetdatachanged on adapter?

Comment: You should call it where you are updating your adapter with data.

Comment: adapter=new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenActivity.this,all_url);

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
added like this.but not working.